# Handle expected return from Spring Integration File

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following configuration file for Spring Integration File:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class MyIntegrationConfiguration {

    private static final String FILE_CHANNEL_PROCESSING = "processingfileChannel";
    private static final String INTERVAL_PROCESSING = "5000";
    private static final String FILE_PATTERN = "*.txt";

    @Value("${import.path.source}")
    private String sourceDir;

    @Value("${import.path.output}")
    private String outputDir;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = FILE_CHANNEL_PROCESSING, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = INTERVAL_PROCESSING))
    public MessageSource<File> sourceFiles() {
        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        source.setDirectory(new File(sourceDir));
        source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(FILE_PATTERN));
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = FILE_CHANNEL_PROCESSING)
    public MessageHandler processedFiles() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(outputDir));
        handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        handler.setExpectReply(true);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processFileFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(FILE_CHANNEL_PROCESSING)
            .transform(fileToStringTransformer())
            .handle("fileProcessor", "processFile").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel fileChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileProcessor fileProcessor() {
        return new FileProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileToStringTransformer fileToStringTransformer() {
        return new FileToStringTransformer();
    }
}
```

For `FileWritingMessageHandler` from [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/FileWritingMessageHandler.html#setExpectReply-boolean-) it says that if `setExpectReply(true)` is set:

> Specify whether a reply Message is expected. If not, this handler will simply return null for a successful response or throw an Exception for a non-successful response.

My question is: where can I catch these exceptions or where can I retrieve this message/response?

Answer (score 0):

The `@ServiceActivator` has an `outputChannel` attribute:

```
/**
 * Specify the channel to which this service activator will send any replies.
 * @return The channel name.
 */
String outputChannel() default "";
```

That's for successful replies.

Any exceptions (independently of the `setExpectReply()`) are just thrown to the caller. In your case the story is about an `@InboundChannelAdapter`. In this case the exception is caught and wrapped to the `ErrorMessage` to be sent to the `errorChannel` on the `@Poller`. It is a global `errorChannel` by default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

However you have some other problem in your code. I see the second *subscriber*  to the `FILE_CHANNEL_PROCESSING`. If it's not a `PublishSubscribeChannel`, you are going to have a round-robin distribution for messages sent to this channel. But that's already a different story. Just don't ask that question here, please!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still haven't been able to achieve what I wanted to do. The Spring Integration is a bit fuzzy for me, and especially since the documentation is talking about xml configuration files, which I do not want to use. I want to achieve everything with annotations and no xml files whatsoever. I'm gonna give it another try in the upcoming days.

Comment: Maybe you just don’t explain properly what you need to do? I don’t know how else to help you: there is only one way to achieve what you provide so far